# Mkpolyline is not being drawn

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, mkmapview, mkpolyline

The route is clearly being made but the polyline is not drawn. I am able to find the total distance, and have verified that the coordinates we are using are not (0,0). Is there something wrong with the delegate, since it seems that both the addOverlay and addAnnotation (called in a custom method shown below called createAndAddAnnotationForCoordinate) methods are not working?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//generates map view
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 
self.view.bounds.size.height)];
//setting delegate to self is not fixing the error
mapView.delegate = self;


mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;




//converting CLLocationCoordinate2D to MKPlacemark
MKPlacemark *startPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
initWithCoordinate: addressOneCoords addressDictionary:

[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil]];
MKPlacemark *endPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate: addressTwoCoords addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil]];

//converting MKPlacemark to MKMapItem
MKMapItem *start = [[MKMapItem alloc ]initWithPlacemark:startPlacemark];

MKMapItem *end = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:endPlacemark];


MKDirectionsRequest *request = [MKDirectionsRequest new];
[request setSource:start];
[request setDestination:end];
[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile];
request.requestsAlternateRoutes = YES;

//Just to check if the coordinates were transferred successfully between view controllers and they did transfer successfully
NSLog(@"address one lat is %f",addressOneCoords.latitude);
NSLog(@"address one lon is %f",addressOneCoords.longitude);
NSLog(@"address two lat is %f",addressTwoCoords.latitude);
NSLog(@"address two lon is %f",addressTwoCoords.longitude);

MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc]initWithRequest:request];

[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse response, NSError error){
    //if the route can't be created
    if(error){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Unable to create route" message:@"Go back to check if addresses are valid" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else{

        [mapView removeOverlays:self.mapView.overlays];

        MKRoute *mainRoute = [response.routes firstObject];



        routeLine = mainRoute.polyline;


        if(routeLine){
            [self.mapView removeOverlay:routeLine];
        }

        //the addOverlay method is not drawing the polyline
        [self.mapView addOverlay: routeLine level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];

        //proof that route is being created successfully
        NSLog(@"Total distance is %f", mainRoute.distance);

        MKMapPoint middlePoint = mainRoute.polyline.points[mainRoute.polyline.pointCount/2];

        //also, the addannotation method is not being called either it seems like
        [self createAndAddAnnotationForCoordinate:MKCoordinateForMapPoint(middlePoint)];


    }
}];


}
```

Our createAndAddAnnotationForCoordinate method,

```
 -(void) createAndAddAnnotationForCoordinate : (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{

MKPointAnnotation* annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
annotation.title = @"Point";
annotation.subtitle = @"subtitle";
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];


}
```

Our overridden mapviewdelegate method,

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer )mapView:(MKMapView )mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{

if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]){
MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc]initWithOverlay:overlay];
renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
renderer.lineWidth = 10.0f;

return renderer;
}

else
    return nil;
}
```

The output if address one was somewhere in NJ and address two was somewhere in CA:

```
address one lat is 40.902599
address one lon is -74.407097
address two lat is 34.054435
address two lon is -118.253393
Total distance is 4459771.000000
```

Comment: Without posting some code like the creation of the MKPolyline and/or the rendererForOverlay delegate method, it is impossible for someone to tell why it's not being drawn.  At the top of the page, click on Help and take the Tour to learn how to ask a proper question.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. I'm a noob to this site. I included the code, please help. Thank you

Comment: In viewDidLoad, you are creating a mapView (alloc+init) but you are not adding it to the view hierarchy (addSubview).  If you already have a map view in Interface Builder, you don't need to create one.  In IB, just make sure the mapView IBOutlet is connected and that its delegate is connected as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, the advice you gave me about adding the subview worked! However now the mapview is taking up the entire screen and I only want it taking it up part of the screen. May I ask how you would check if the delegate is connect to the mkmapview in the interface builder?

Comment: Wait nvm, I found out the answer to my concern in my previous question. This question has been answered successfully. Thank you to Anna and Adam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ron, I'm suspecting your polyline (`mainRoute.polyline`) - your rendererForOverlay looks almost exactly like one I am using successfully. Barring the very basic mistakes like not setting the MKMapView delegate, or setting it to some other object, I would be almost sure the polyline you add to the map does not contain valid CLLocationCoordinate2D structs.

In Swift, creation goes like

```
    var coordinatePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>(track2DCoordinates)
    let trackPolygon = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinatePtr, count: track2DCoordinates.count)
    mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)
    mapView.addOverlay(trackPolygon)
```

Start by verifying that you really have a valid MKPolyline.

I'm also not sure about your `middlePoint` calculation.

```
MKMapPoint middlePoint = mainRoute.polyline.points[mainRoute.polyline.pointCount/2];
```

This kind of thing probably works right now but in Swift you need to be a lot more careful of the data types used as index. What if you have an odd number of points, or zero?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did set the MKMapView delegate, so it could have something to do with the CLLocationCoordinate2D structs. However, the MKRoute was still made successfully. But you are most certainly right about the index of my midpoint. Could the polyline error have something to do with the MKRoute or conversion from CLLocationCoordinate2D to MKMapItem?